# Not able to iterate HTMLCollection in jQuery extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am working on form filler. Below code is working fine in Chrome console, but when I put the code in extension (form filler) it does not work.

jQuery Code:

```js
var addressElement=$($('[data-name="selected-address"]')[0].children).filter(function(idx) {
    return this.innerHTML.indexOf('52') == 0;
});
addressElement[0].click();
```

Also tried JavaScript code

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[ng-bind="address.formattedAddress"]');
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="select-replacement form-control" data-name="selected-address">
    <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="selectAddress(address);" ng-repeat="address in address.addressList" ng-bind="address.formattedAddress" class="ng-binding ng-scope">30, test data</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="selectAddress(address);" ng-repeat="address in address.addressList" ng-bind="address.formattedAddress" class="ng-binding ng-scope">52, test data2</a>
</div>
```

Note: I have tried all the possible options in Google. However, the above selector does not return array list of a tags. Please note that it works in developer console.

Comment: If you are wanting all the `<a>` which are the direct children of that `<div>` why are you not just directly using the selector: `'[data-name="selected-address"] > a'`? Also, in general, you should avoid the use of `.innerHTML` unless you are *sure* that it's what you *need*. In this case, you are looking for text, so you should be using `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Have you tried logging the result of your `$('[data-name="selected-address"]')[0].children` to make sure that those elements exist at the time your code executes? The most likely issue is that they are added dynamically after your code runs. There are, of course, other possibilities, but without a complete [mcve] *that duplicates the problem*, we have to *guess* at what the problem is.

Comment: @makyen. yes logged it already . it returns HTMLCollection(18). i tried to loop it through using for of , for in and normal for loop but it does not loop.

 for(i=0;i<$('[data-name="selected-address"]')[0].children.length;i++){

            console.log(i+"--------"+list[i]);

        }

also tried to convert in array

var list=$('[data-name="selected-address"]')[0].children;
        //var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( list );
        //var arr = [].slice.call(list);

which returns blank array

Comment: Unless you expect the collection to change *don't* regenerate it each time through the loop to test the `length`, that causes a DOM walk each time, which is just burning compute cycles for no reason. Assign the collection to a variable. Straight iteration by index should work. While I prefer more complex/faster ways, converting to Array could be as simple as `[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="selected-address"] > a')]`, then you could use `.forEach()` (assumes there's only one `selected-address`). Basically, we are going to need a *complete* [mcve] which duplicates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue adding some delay in my code through setInterval

Answer (score -1):

```
addressElement[0].click();
```

to

```
$(addressElement[0]).click();
```

Comment: How does this help? The DOM element already has a [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), which should work just fine.